# Regex, How to match only one char after lazy operator

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix, lazy-evaluation

This: (v)(?:\w*?e){1}(r)

Applied to this: **vgdsefer**

Matches "**vgdsefer**" where i think that

First group matches "**v**"

Second group matches "**gdsefe**"

Third group matches "**r**"

Shouldnt **(?:\w*?e)** be matched only once? In "**gdsefe**" it matches "**gdse**" and "**fe**".

For what i understand "**\w*?e**" matches any char until **e** is found and the **{}** makes it only match one time so if it finds "**gdse**" it shouldnt match "**fe**" after

Thanks for your help, i am learning regex and tried to solve this for hours with no success

Comment: The lazy quantifier finds the shortest possible string that results in an overall match - the final `r` extends the match.

Comment: jspcal I see now that r is tue problem, is there a way to dont extend the match?

Comment: Not without limiting the size of that group as in `\w{0,3}`

Comment: The main question is whether or not you want to find any match in `vgdsefer`. If  you exclude `e` from `\w`, you will have no match: `(v)(?:(?!e)\w)*?e(r)`